# Playback state control of spotify web player sdk using spotify api

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django, spotify

I am creating a webapp using django and react in which multiple user can control playback of a spotify player (play/pause, skip). This is useful in case of a house party or something where people are listening to a common device . I am thinking if i can integrate the spotify web player sdk and all users can listen to synced playback and control at the sametime remotely. I understand single spotify account needs to register that webapp to be used as device. My question is if can i control the state of playback if the page is opened by multiple users so that they listen to a song synchronously.

Comment: Hi! This is not a well researched question. Please do your research and post questions here where either you do not find the solution on searching or you are facing trouble in implementing it. I am sorry to down vote, but I have to. Good luck in researching about this.

Answer (score 0):

#### IDEA:

You can make a "Room" in your webapp like every room will generate a unique ID for every room and a **Password** any person who want to enter this room will use this **Password** to enter that room.

#### How to Sync every song  ?

This is the hard part but you can  do it using sockets (my recommendation,... you can also use something else). Socket will enable you to send information (if anyone changed, play, pause or stoped the song) to every user who are accessing that room you have to change, play, pause or stop the song accordingly.